# Replace nullable parameter in lambda expression with value

Tags: c#, lambda

Is it possible to replace `Expression<Func<Nullable<TValue>>>` with `Expression<Func<TValue>>`?

Where value is `Nullable<TValue>.GetValueOrDefault()`.

Comment: btw, `Expression<Func<Nullable<TValue>>>` **doesn't have** any parameters

Comment: my meaning was: the question title doesn't fit the example; unless perhaps you mean the *generic type parameter* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to replace `Expression<Func<Nullable<TValue>>>` with `Expression<Func<TValue>>`?

Sure - that is just wrapping the outermost result of the lambda:

```
static void Main() {

    Expression<Func<int?>> x = () => 1, y = () => null;
    Expression<Func<int>> a = DeNullify(x), b = DeNullify(y);

    Console.WriteLine(x.Compile()()); // 1
    Console.WriteLine(y.Compile()()); // {blank; null}

    Console.WriteLine(a.Compile()()); // 1
    Console.WriteLine(b.Compile()()); // 0 
}
public static Expression<Func<TValue>> DeNullify<TValue>(
    Expression<Func<TValue?>> expression) where TValue : struct
{
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TValue>>(
        Expression.Call(expression.Body, "GetValueOrDefault", null),
        expression.Parameters);
}
```